# UWP visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I want to develop an application for my nokia lumia 1320.I 've searched and found that UWP only develops for windows 10 phone but my phone cant be further updated to windows 10 from windows 8.1.Please guide me through.I 've looked for older versions of VS but i guess MS has removed them.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to use VS2015 to develop for WP81. You are right it is not exactly easy for find an installer for VS2015, but links in this article work: http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2015/07/download-visualstudio-2015.html#2ial3gRLXvav52pU.97

Comment: Thankyou so much.After 3 days of struggle i just found this link from microsoft 
https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=%20Visual%20Studio%202015%20community